# ¿Cómo puedo abrir los archivos .ipynb de una máquina virtual que ejecuta un jupyterhub?

Tags: jupyter, virtualización, jupyterhub

utiliso un jupyterhub y tengo archivos .ipynb que deseo abrir

```
! ls ~/../shared/Text_Mining/Code/finetuned-camemBERT.ipynb
finetuned-camemBERT.ipynb  finetuned-camemBERT.py  inference-camemBERT.ipynb
```

Me gustaria abrirlos en jupyterhub pero no fue capaz de abrirlos porque no se cual path dar a Jupyterhub para abrirlos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una solución simple es crear un enlace al directorio:

```sh
!ln -s ~/../shared shared
```

A partir de ahora verás esos notebooks dentro del directorio `shared`.